# I have a problem displaying data using bootstrap-select library in my select tag in Angular 8 & Bootstrap 4

Tags: angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

Using Angular 8 & Bootstrap 4

I am trying to implement searching in a select tag using bootstrap-select library from https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ .
Below is my html

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="field_bankName" name="bankName" formControlName="bankName">
        <option *ngIf="!editForm.get('bankName').value" [ngValue]="null"></option>
        <option [ngValue]="paymentMethodOption.id === editForm.get('bankName').value?.id ? editForm.get('bankName').value : paymentMethodOption" *ngFor="let paymentMethodOption of paymentmethods; trackBy: trackPaymentMethodById">{{paymentMethodOption.bankName}}</option>
</select>
```

I call selectpicker js in my ngOnInit() function

```
(<any>$('.selectpicker')).selectpicker();
```

I already import the bootstrap-select.min.css in my styles.css, and it looks fine.

```
@import url(assets/css/bootstrap-select.min.css);
```

I also import the bootstrap-select.min.js in my index.html

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

I have a problem in displaying data to select tag, I can't display the data. When I don't use the bootstrap-select library, the data is displayed fine.

But when I insert dummy options such as: "Halo" & "Bandung" like my code below, it shows both "Halo" & "Bandung", only. It doesn't show my data.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="field_bankName" name="bankName" formControlName="bankName">
      <option *ngIf="!editForm.get('bankName').value" [ngValue]="null"></option>
      <option [ngValue]="paymentMethodOption.id === editForm.get('bankName').value?.id ? editForm.get('bankName').value : paymentMethodOption" *ngFor="let paymentMethodOption of paymentmethods; trackBy: trackPaymentMethodById">{{paymentMethodOption.bankName}}</option>
      <option value="">Halo</option>
      <option value="">Bandung</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Did you include everything else, like popper.js and so on, as per instructions?

Comment: yes, I included popper.min.js above bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-select.min.js @KaseyChang . The search box is there, but it doesn't show my data.

Comment: but when I insert static option data:
<option value="">Halo</option>
<option value="">Bandung</option>
it shows both "Halo" & "Bandung" @KaseyChang

Comment: You need to debug this one step at a time. Add some javascript before the select to console.log the values like bankName, ngValue, and so on. Right now we're not even sure it's loading bootstrap-select. Did Console show any errors?